# Jquery planner calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

Hoping someone has stumble on something that would help me, I am trying to add a jquery calendar to my site, and the only ones I can seem to find are ones that have hourly events, for one person. I am looking for a grid, booked out type thing. My explanation is poor so I brought pictures. Something like.

[image: Grid layout]

So basically I can add a list of items and what days they are marked out. Sort of a booking system. I don't need hourly, just daily markers.

Anyone know one? If not I am going to have to write my own.

Thanks.

Comment: `"I am going to have to write my own"` - And with that effort we will be happy to help you anywhere that you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a calendar?  You have no dates its a weekly concept, and you can do everything you need with tables or divs.

You just need  to return a json object with a person and their availability.

```
data = {
  'schedule': [
    {
    'name': 'Car1',
    'week': 51,
    'availability':  {
         'mon': True,
         'tue': False,
         //etc
     }
     }, /etc
   ]
  }
```

or

```
data = {
   // ...
  'availability': [1,0,0,0,0,0,1]
}
```

Just my two cents, I dont see any particular need for a calendar.

Comment: The image was just the sort of output I am trying for, I would like to have the prev/next functionality of something like fullcalender. Ideally I would like the dates at the top instead of weekdays.